# Mapping two prompted values in the same command line to two variables in C++

Tags: c++, iostream

it is a very simple thing but I didn't know how to look it up on Google so here it goes.
I would like the user to be able to enter values for two variables in the same line:

```
Enter the values for x and y:
2 4
The values entered are x = 2 and y = 4
```

I know std::cin just reads the first word given a string... What about std::getline? The problem is that I want numerical data though...

```
std::cout << "Enter the values for x and y:" << std::endl;
std::string name
std::getline (std::cin,name);
// now what??
std::cout << "The values you entered are x = " << x << " and y = " << y <<std::endl;
```

Is there any different approach? A simpler way to do it... We could iterate over the string and splitting into different words by studying the position of the space ASCII character, but that would take a lot of time, there must be a built-in library that allows you to do that...

Comment: Forget Google. Research goes beyond Googling. You could have found this out simply by reading the first couple of chapters of your C++ book!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are over-thinking the problem. `std::cin` can get values for type `int` or `double` directly:

```
int x, y;
std::cin >> x >> y;
```

Comment: Really? I went too far again... haha. Thanks a lot @YuHao